# Respresenting a 3 Dimensional Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I represent a 3 dimensional Sparse Tensor in Tensorflow?
For 2 dimensions I use

```
SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]], values=[1, 2], dense_shape=[3, 4])
```

With result

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 2, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Its hard to show a visual for a 3 dimension but i'll try

```
SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]], [1,1,2], values=[1, 2,3], dense_shape=[3, 4,2])

  [[1, 0, 0, 0]
   [0, 0, 2, 0]
   [0, 0, 0, 0],

   [0, 0, 0, 0]
   [0, 0, 3, 0]
   [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This is somewhat what I want to have. Could anybody help me with this? Can't get my mind around how SparseTensor want me to write the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just put a `]` in the wrong place.

```
SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1,2,1]], values=[1,2,3], dense_shape=[3,4,2])
```

gives you the desired matrix.

As per the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor),

> dense_shape: A 1-D int64 tensor of dense_shape [ndims], which specifies the dense_shape of the sparse tensor. Takes a list indicating the number of elements in each dimension. For example, dense_shape=[3,6] specifies a two-dimensional 3x6 tensor, dense_shape=[2,3,4] specifies a three-dimensional 2x3x4 tensor, and dense_shape=[9] specifies a one-dimensional tensor with 9 elements.